# Cant see runtime log in Pycharm for Windows

Tags: python, logging, pycharm, runtime, pytest

I'm using pytest with pycharm for Windows to run tests. When running the test, the logging information on the console window on pycharm is only displayed at the end of the running and not during running.
On linux, same test and run are working fine and the log is displayed in runtime.

How can I make it so that the logs will be displayed during runtime on Windows as well?

Thanks

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Please, add an example, how are you running your tests. Try `pytest -s -v test_login.py`